# Syntax for dynamically creating object

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am working with creating an object, and i am having trouble recalling the syntax to create a new object if the query comes up with 0 results.

I saw it in documentation but can't seem to find it anymore.

EDIT:

My if statement is suppose to insert a dummy insert into a table but i get DML errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dphil's answer is quite right (upvoted), but he is also correct that a lot of clarity would be useful here.

If you just want to check for a value and then create an object off the back of that, it can be achieved more concisely with something like (taking dphils lead)

```
if([SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Name = 'name'].size() == 0) {
    Account acc = new Account(Name = 'name');
    // insert acc; //etc.etc.
}
```

Comment: I suppose clarity of the question is they key here.  My way will allow you to have access to the object afterwards, and your way(Simon's) just ensures that it exists.

Comment: I concur. The asker may wish to augment their question :)

Comment: This was what i was looking for great!

Comment: Followup question i get DML errors with an insert at that point. Any idea what may be causing it

Comment: That may be worthy of another question? What object are you inserting, where are you doing this (Apex class/Trigger etc.) and what the error message/debug logs say.. lots of possibilities there!

Answer (score 2):

You might need a little more clarity on your question....

```
List accs = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Name = :someName LIMIT 1];
Account acc;
if (accs.size() > 0)
{
  acc = accs[0];
} else
{
  acc = new Account(Name = someName);
  //insert acc;//Did you want it created right away?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a million ways to do this, so here's another.  Use try / catch exception handling instead of if / else and size checks.

Note, this solution will only work if you're expecting a single record back.

```
Account acct = null;
try{
    //The following will throw an exception if no accounts are found.
    acct = [Select Name From Account Where Id=:acct.Id];
}catch(QueryException e){
    acct = new Account(Name='I was just created, upsert me if you dare');
}
```